# win8 store app access local storage

Tags: windows-8

I am developing a Win8 Store app which allows users to download **different types** of files from an online learning platform and store them locally. I am also considering the function to help users organize these downloaded files by placing them in different folders (based on course name and etc.).

I was using Documents Library previously. But for every type of file that the user could download, I need to add a file type association, which does not make a lot of sense since my app would be able to open such files. So which local storage should my app use?

Many thanks in advance.

Kaizhi

Comment: Does the user always access the files through your app or does he need/want to interact with them in the file browser or share them with other apps?

Comment: the users would want to access the files through file explorer as well. that is why I would like to store the files in an "easy-to-find" location like Documents library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access to storage by Windows Store apps is quite restrictive, especially the DocumentsLibrary.

As you have noticed, you need to declare a file type association for every file type you want to read from or write to the DocumentsLibrary. This means your app need to handle file activations for these types in a meaningful way, which your app probably should not do.

But even if you jump through this hoop, there is another one that is not documented on the [MSDN page of the DocumentsLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary), but "hidden" in a [lengthy page about app capability declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936): According to the current rules, you are **not allowed to use the DocumentsLibrary for anything but offline access to SkyDrive!** Bummer...

So what's left?

You can use SkyDrive or another cloud storage to put files in a well known place (which might or might not be somewhere on the hard disk). This is probably both overkill and undesirable in your case.

Or you save the files in the [local app storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700361.aspx), provide your own in-app file browser and [open the files with their default app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779671.aspx). Seems viable to me.

Or, maybe, you can do something with [share contracts or other contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx). I don't know much about these yet, but I doubt that they are helpful in your situation.

And that's it...

(Based on my current experience. No guaranty for correctness or completeness)

Comment: thanks for the information. it helps a lot. what about downloads library? is it possible for me to create well-organized folders inside?

Comment: @user1437038: I don't know if/how an app can access that. It's not part of the KnownFolders http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx . Don't forget to upvote/accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: i think I have figured out how to implement this. I should create folders inside Downloads folder and use FutureAccessList to store these folders (so that next time I should still have access right to these folders). Anyway, I will accept your answer. Thanks for your effort!